# spring security, method secure and url secure

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm learning spring security, but I get confused with it's flexibility..

I know I can secure the urls by defining rules in  tag
then I saw there is a @secure annotation which can secure methods.
and then there are other annotations to secure Read/update by domains (or POJOs)

so when I want to develop a typical permission/role/users web application, beside creating rules to secure urls, do I also have to use @secure annotation to secure methods?

ej.

1. user enter the restricted url
2. application ask to login
3. application check if the role can access the url
4. user select "add new" option
5. check again if that user has permission to call the method "addNew()"??

or one of step 4 or 5 is redundant.

sorry about my English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the most important thing to remember. You *must* assume that a user can send *anything* to your web application via a raw HTTP GET or POST. This is also called "never trust the client." So steps 4 and 5 above are not redundant. If you reach step 5, for instance, you can't be sure that step 3 occurred.

That said, if you can accurately differentiate what the user is intending to do via the URL alone *and* you don't need to secure the method through a different access channel (say from a queue or RMI), you can get away with only securing the URL. However, it's still not a bad idea to have method-level security regardless of this... for a couple of reasons. First, it documents the expected roles right where the logic is being performed. That can be helpful for understanding the assumptions that were made at development time which can help with making future enhancements. Second, it can ensure that the security through a future access channel won't inadvertently be compromised.

Comment: thank you for you answer. so if I secure every mothod/class, do I still have to secure URLs? or maybe combining just a simple rule for anonymous/user/admin pattern

Comment: If your URLs are grouped roughly by role, it would probably be easier to secure by URL (e.g., the 'admin/**' URL requiring ROLE_ADMIN). But often you either can't structure your app that way, the roles are more complex than that, or the URLs themselves don't provide much information at all (i.e., most of the information is in the request body). But it's a good idea to have some catch-alls at the URL level, particularly for your non-Java based files (if you have any and are serving them up in the web app).

Answer (score 5):

URL level security is quite rich, as one can see by looking at the fluent [API of HttpSecurity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.htmlhttp://), for example.
But there are at least two reasons for using method level security in Spring security:

1. As pointed out by Jonathan W, your secured logic may be accessible via connector types other than http. For example, the logic may be exposed via EJBs.
2. For REST APIs, the same URI may support different http methods that have different authorization rules. For example `/myapi/order/{id}` may accept GET and DELETE, and DELETE may be available only to users with Supervisor role. You cannot specify that rule via URL security, but you can do so via method security, for example using `@Secured("Supervisor")` on the method that handles DELETE.